# How to echo text and read input after every line of a file?

Tags: list, printing, awk

Been working on a project of my own (actually learning bash programming) and came across a step which I have been stuck for a couple of days.

I pretend to use `awk` to print the first line of a file, then print fields for manual completion under that line. I want that it repeats that process for every line in that file.

My script below prints all lines of the file above the list, and loops forever. It should stop at the last line.

That is what I've gotten:

```
while awk -F"|" 'NR' resultado.txt; do
    echo "Histórico:"
    read Historico
    echo "Conta:"
    read Conta2
    echo "Valor:"
    read Valor
done
```

Example:

Lines from the file to be processed:

```
LAURVOGT|    31|02/05/2015|6.1.1.01.001|2.1.1.01.005||8,100|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||31,000|N|N|||0,000|
LAURVOGT|    34|03/05/2015|6.1.1.01.002|2.1.1.01.005||6,900|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||34,000|N|N|||0,000|
```

How they should be processed:

```
LAURVOGT|    31|02/05/2015|6.1.1.01.001|2.1.1.01.005||8,100|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||31,000|N|N|||0,000|
```

Historico:

(Should be able to type info, and when I'm done next "Conta" shows up below)

Conta:

(Should be able to type info, and when I'm done next "Valor" shows up below)

Valor:

(Should be able to type info, and when I'm done the command repeats all this for the next line, until the last one from the file)

Could anyone please guide me to my desired result?

Comment: The `awk` command prints the whole file (`NR` will always be non-zero unless the file is empty), and succeeds.  The script then prompts for and reads three values, but it needs to echo those values too.  It also isn't clear how you want the output handled; everything goes to standard output, probably the terminal — both the prompts and any echoed responses.  Did you want the data in a file?  You need to be careful handling two input streams (the file and the terminal) and two output streams (the terminal for prompts, and another file, presumably, for the overall result).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you show us sample input and desired output?

Comment: HI Jonathan, Let me better explain. I have a file with lines that miss information. So i want the command start printing the first line of the file, then bellow the line a title "Historico:" and under "Historico:" i should be able to type information. The missing informations are "Historico:", "Conta:" and "Valor:". So i want that each of those show under each of the lines of the file, and under each of these "Headings" i should be able to type something.

Comment: I more or less understand what you want.  I'm wondering which shell you're using.  Bash's `read` command has a `-u` option that allows you to specify where data is to come from; that's what you need here.  I'm not sure what Korn shell provides; classic (and POSIX) shells don't make it so easy.

Comment: Im using apple macbook pro 2015. Will try applying your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer, but note that I'm not clear on your revision.  Also, please, please, please, please learn to indent 'code' (and data) in the question.  Type it as you want it to appear, then select it all, then press the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.  My code was tested on a new MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work not using Bash extensions to the `read` command.  It works with Bash run as `sh` and with `ksh`.  I wrote it before the sample data got added to the question.  I'm not going to rewrite it, but the problem just got more complex.

#### `reader.sh`

```
while read -r line <&3
do
    echo "$line" >&4
    echo "Histórico: "
    read -r Historico
    echo "$Historico" >&4
    echo "Conta: "
    read -r Conta2
    echo "$Conta2" >&4
    echo "Valor: "
    read -r Valor
    echo "$Valor" >&4
done 3<resultado.txt 4>output.txt
```

Lots of I/O redirection.  The output goes to file descriptor 4, which is pointed at the file `output.txt`.  The file input is on file descriptor 3, coming from `resultado.txt`.   The `read` command at the top of the loop redirects its standard input from file descriptor 3, which means it reads the next line of `resultado.txt`.  The `echo "Xyz: "` commands in the body of the echo to the terminal (standard output).  There are ways to suppress the newline after the `echo`, but they're shell-dependent (`echo -n` is one way; `echo "Xyz: \c"` is another).  The `read -r Xyz` commands in the loop body read from the terminal.  The `echo "$Xyz" >&4` commands send the output to file descriptor 4, as does the `echo "$line"`.

If you have Bash, you can use `read -r -u 3 line` instead of the `read` with I/O redirection.  You could also use `read -p 'Valor: ' -r Valor` to prompt for and read the inputs.

#### `resultado.txt`

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
```

#### Example run

I don't like typing, so I had a random number generator generate enough data.  It does work when I use myself as the generator of the random inputs.

```
$ random -n 9 -F "RNG: %.2d" 0 99 | sh reader.sh
Histórico: 
Conta: 
Valor: 
Histórico: 
Conta: 
Valor: 
Histórico: 
Conta: 
Valor: 
$
```

#### `output.txt`

```
This is the first line.
RNG: 66
RNG: 49
RNG: 02
This is the second line.
RNG: 18
RNG: 90
RNG: 36
This is the third line.
RNG: 56
RNG: 22
RNG: 95
```

#### Revised question

There are many fields in the input.  It is not clear what you're supposed to do with the input line, or the prompted for data.  If you need to edit the responses into the line, then you've got a much more fearsome job ahead.

Comment: Yes i need to place the typed infos into the lines from resultado.txt. My purpose is to make a script that will pick a txt file exported from one software, and edit that file to a new layout to be imported on a second software. 
Should i continue this job on bash, or jump to other language such as python?

Comment: Have fun.   You're on your own with that.  There are too many undefined issues to resolve — your question simply doesn't specify where the new inputs are to go in the output.  You can use the ideas from the script I show to handle the input.  You then need to revise the output to meet your requirements, but since those are completely unclear at the moment, there's nothing I can do to help.

Comment: I should have added: if you have the revised/extended requirements carefully specified and you run into a problem implementing the code, then you can always come back with a new question.  Avoid creating 'chameleon' questions, please.